# Overriding an overridden class in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

Is it possible to generally override all the overridden classes in Magento?

For example, if I override the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute`, I should be able to override all the classes which have already been overridden by some other classes.

Comment: Are you asking if (for example) you can override, say, `Mage_Catalog_Block_Template`, and then have all classes which inherit from that class overridden as well? If so the answer is no unless you want to modify core classes and bind `Varien_Autoload` to `Mage_Core_Model_Config`/confic XML.